# Trying to pass concatenated JavaScript string to getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an error saying:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

My JavaScript is:

```
function AddAFacultyMember(){
    for(x=2;x<=10;x++){

        var str0 = "'";
        var str1 = 'Faculty';
        var str2 = x;
        var str3 = 'input';
        var str4 = "'";

        var concat = str0.concat(str1,str2,str3,str4);

        if( document.getElementById(concat).style.display =='none' ){
            var eligible = concat;
            return;
        }

        document.getElementById(eligible).style.display == 'block';

    }

}
```

An example of one of the Faculty div IDs is "Faculty1input". What's the issue?

Comment: Get rid of `str0` and `str4`. The `concat` variable passes its content to getElementByID; you don't need the quotes. Also,  `eligible` will be undefined if the if statement is false.

Comment: Print out the contents of `concat` (`console.log(concat)`) and check it in your console (hit F12). Does it match any IDs set in the HTML?

Comment: @j08691 correct & also define str2 & str3 outside the function

Comment: tested with getting rid of str0 and str4; same error ...

Comment: I did a test with alert(concat) ... it matches the HTML div ID I'm trying to test on ...

Comment: @vinayakj There's no reason to declare those variables outside of the function. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: @faalbane unless you have an element having `id=<value of concat>` then it will fail

Comment: var `elegible` is defined in the wrong scope

Comment: @MikeC I already mentioned answer is given, just trying to improve OP's code

Comment: Can you post a *complete* code example so we can see the error in action?

Comment: @vinayakj How does that improve it? They just end up with some leaky variables that could be reassigned elsewhere.

Comment: @MikeC that's the point they wont

Comment: @vinayakj That doesn't even make sense. If you declare variables *outside* of the function then that means any functions declared within that same scope can access and modify those variables. If you only want to use some values within a given function, there's no reason to declare them outside of the function. You just open the possibility for those variables to get changed (unless they're declared with `const` and aren't reference types).

Comment: @MikeC exactly like you said, they are constants & shouldnt be declared multiple times with same value like OP had, also that way he can have single point of entry for changing constant value.

Comment: found it; posted solution; thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
function AddAFacultyMember(){
    for(x=2;x<=10;x++){
        var concat = 'Faculty' + x + 'input';
        var ele = document.getElementById(concat);
        if( ele.style.display =='none' ){
            ele.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  Specifically, concat only accepts strings, and the original code was taking an int.

Comment: var `elegible` is defined in the wrong scope this still should fail. `eligible` is undefined in this example for varios scenarios

Comment: @Dalorzo JS uses function scoping so although it *looks* like `eligible` is declared in the wrong scope, it really isn't. `eligible` is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the top of the function.

Comment: Code has been clarified for simplicity. Not sure if it has strayed from what the OP was asking... But it will do what his code was attempting.

Answer (score 1):

found the issue!

the double == wasn't restyling the display of getElementById(eligible) to 'block' though it was correctly constructing the string. Solution/fix:

```
document.getElementById(eligible).style.display = 'block';
```

also removed str0 and str4:

```
function AddAFacultyMember(){
    for(x=2;x<=10;x++){ 
        var str1 = 'Faculty'; 
        var str2 = x; 
        var str3 = 'input'; 
        var concat =str1.concat(str2,str3);

        if( document.getElementById(concat).style.display =='none' ){

            var eligible = concat;
            document.getElementById(eligible).style.display = 'block';
            eligible = '';
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the change you mentioned. BTW that is not really an issue... It may not have done what you wanted it to do, but it was not creating the issue you posted. Your issue was that you were adding `'` to the string...

Comment: thanks Vinny! I see your update and have upvoted your answer! I agree that the eligible var is unnecessary ... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
función AddAFacultyMember({ 
    for(x=2;x<=10;x++){ 
        var str1 = 'Faculty'; 
        var str2 = x; 
        var str3 = 'input'; 
        var concat =str1.concat(str2,str3);
       ...
```